# Cannot get my two values to recognise there is a match

Tags: python

I'm creating a program to validate the GTIN 8 digit code in Python. I've got to the point where it checks the 8 digit number against the GTINs in the following text file.

```
34512340    plain brackets      0.50
98981236    product notfound    0.00
56756777    100mm bolts     0.20
90673412    L-shaped brackets   1.20
```

But, my code will not recognise the match, it just passes straight through the the else statement. I've tried casting where I can because I have a feeling they are not both classified as integers. Any ideas?

```
import sys

digitentry=int(input("Please enter the product number for validation purposes"))

productNo=[int(i) for i in str(digitentry)]

num1=productNo[0]*3  
num2=productNo[1]*1
num3=productNo[2]*3
num4=productNo[3]*1
num5=productNo[4]*3
num6=productNo[5]*1
num7=productNo[6]*3

list2 = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7]
list_sum = sum(list2)

import math


def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10

ten=(roundup(list_sum))

dig8=ten-list_sum

GTIN = int(str(digitentry)+ str(dig8))
print(GTIN)

if ten%10==0:
    print ("Thanks for confirming the product number")
else:
    print("This product number is not valid")

with open("stock.txt", "r") as datafile:
           for line in datafile:
                      print (line.split()[0])

if line == GTIN:
           print("Yes")
else:
           print("No")
```

Comment: For example, i tried 34512340 and it said there was no match (i.e printed no)

Comment: Well, try like this: `if line != GTIN: print '%r != %r' % (line, GTIN)`. Then you'll know what is wrong.

Comment: @Corb691 My answer works. Plus, I have a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is that you need to store the result of `str.split` otherwise `line` doesn't change, it is still the whole line in the file. Second is that you also need to convert the split portion to a `int` for comparison.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        gtin_check = int(line.split()[0])

        if gtin_check == GTIN:
           print("Yes")
        else:
           print("No")
```

Lastly, there is an issue with

```
GTIN = int(str(digitentry)+ str(dig8))
```

As you see when you print your `GTIN` it outputs `345123400` when `34512340` is supplied as the input. An extra digit is added on, I'm unsure though on what you actually want to do here.

---

Additionally, you can cut down the first part to just.

```
from itertools import cycle

digitentry = input("Please enter the product number for validation purposes ")

c = cycle((3, 1))
list_sum = sum(int(i) * next(c) for i in digitentry)
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part of your code. It works! I just wanted it to stop and move to the next phase of the program when it picks up a match. So I added a break to it.

Comment: GTIN = int(str(digitentry)+ str(dig8)) - This concetantes the numbers I entered when the program opens with the final eight digit from the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your code, you are generating the 8th control digit which is then appended to the input. So if you run your code with the following modification with the input `3451234`, it will report a match:

```
with open("stock.txt", "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        cols = line.strip().split()

        if int(cols[0]) == GTIN: #GTIN is an integer
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
```

Comment: Thanks! Your recommendation also give me the desired output. I just added a break statement when a match is found. That allowed me to enter an invalid number an initiate a system exit!

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import sys

digitentry=int(input("Please enter the product number for validation    purposes"))

productNo=[int(i) for i in str(digitentry)]

num1=productNo[0]*3  
num2=productNo[1]*1
num3=productNo[2]*3
num4=productNo[3]*1
num5=productNo[4]*3
num6=productNo[5]*1
num7=productNo[6]*3

list2 = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7]
list_sum = sum(list2)

import math


def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10

ten=(roundup(list_sum))

dig8=ten-list_sum

GTIN = str(digitentry)+ str(dig8)
GTIN = int(GTIN[:-1])

if ten%10==0:
    print ("Thanks for confirming the product number")
else:
    print("This product number is not valid")

with open("stock.txt", "r") as datafile:
           for line in datafile:
               if int(line.split()[0]) == int(GTIN):
                   print("Yes")
               else:
                   print("No")
```

---

**Output**

[image: Output]

---

**Explanation:**

**1)** Everything you put in duplicates the last digit. I tried `98981236` and the output outputted `989812366` so I cut off the last character:

```
GTIN = str(digitentry)+ str(dig8)
GTIN = int(GTIN[:-1])
```

---

**2)** The second issue was that your `if statement` was outside the file reading so it only checked the last result. So I moved it:

```
for line in datafile:
    if int(line.split()[0]) == int(GTIN):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

---

**3)** The last error was that you were comparing the full line to the `GTIN` instead of the split version `line.split()[0]`

Comment: Thanks for this, but point 1 is now not printing off the full GTIN, when I go back to my original code it works.

Comment: The only issue now is, it will now break as soon as a condition is not met. For example, if its a GTIN 2nd,3rd or 4th in the list. If it doesn't match with item 1 then the code will stop at this point.

Comment: It works. @Corb691 I tested it with the second one in the example

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried it and it doesn't work - I don't understand why though.